# How to get the current network traffic via the commandline in a simple format

Tags: command-line, networking

I need to calculate the average network traffic on an interface. I know about software like `iftop`, but I cannot use it in my case.

I am running a program which shall do calculations with the average network traffic on an interface. Therefore, I require a command which produces a *simple* output. Programs like `iftop` output the values in a very complex way which cannot be easily parsed by other applications.

I am looking for something like:

Command:

```
$ get-avg-traffic --interface=eth0 --seconds-interval=30 --type=incoming --unit=KB
```

Output:

```
783846
```

Is there already software which supports (some of) this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to have a look at vnstat

```
$ vnstat -d -i wlp3s0

wlp3s0  /  daily

     day         rx      |     tx      |    total    |   avg. rate
 ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
 2017-10-24   166,63 MiB |   37,33 MiB |  203,96 MiB |   19,34 kbit/s
 2017-10-25   214,68 MiB |  130,26 MiB |  344,94 MiB |   32,71 kbit/s
 2017-10-26     1,01 GiB |    4,09 GiB |    5,10 GiB |  495,31 kbit/s
 2017-10-27     1,16 GiB |  113,28 MiB |    1,27 GiB |  123,04 kbit/s
 2017-10-28   201,09 MiB |  299,21 MiB |  500,31 MiB |   47,44 kbit/s
 2017-10-29     1,92 GiB |  174,35 MiB |    2,09 GiB |  202,92 kbit/s
 2017-10-30   559,56 MiB |   69,18 MiB |  628,73 MiB |   59,61 kbit/s
 2017-10-31   397,73 MiB |   43,62 MiB |  441,35 MiB |   41,85 kbit/s
 2017-11-01   665,81 MiB |   83,05 MiB |  748,86 MiB |   71,00 kbit/s
 2017-11-02   282,20 MiB |  239,91 MiB |  522,11 MiB |   49,50 kbit/s
 2017-11-03     4,06 GiB |    4,85 GiB |    8,92 GiB |  865,61 kbit/s
 2017-11-04   220,95 MiB |   40,12 MiB |  261,07 MiB |   24,75 kbit/s
 2017-11-05   320,91 MiB |    8,86 GiB |    9,18 GiB |  890,93 kbit/s
 2017-11-06   639,67 MiB |   13,77 GiB |   14,39 GiB |    1,40 Mbit/s
 2017-11-07   694,91 MiB |   80,48 MiB |  775,39 MiB |   73,52 kbit/s
 2017-11-08   178,64 MiB |   32,43 MiB |  211,07 MiB |   28,97 kbit/s
 ------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------------
 estimated       257 MiB |      46 MiB |     303 MiB |
```

You can have hourly daily and monthly statistics.

Answer (score 3):

The command `ip` (formerly `netstat`) will give you this type of information but you'll need to do parsing to get just a number AFAICT (I'm no expert on it).

```
localhost-$ ip -s -h -c link show wlan15
```

gives output like:

```
3: wlan15: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1372 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:f3:c1:28:2b:68 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
    78.2M      137k     0       0       0       0       
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    146M       197k     0       0       0       0
```

So for example:

`ip -s -c link show wlan15 | tail -n1 | cut -d " " -f5`

Would give `146013456` or somesuch, the 146M in raw bytes as the transmission volume on the particular interface. `tail` takes the last line (use it with `head` to pick an arbitrary line [there are plenty of other ways]), cut is separating that output in to fields with " " as the delimiter and choosing the fifth field.

Using this value in your program to calculate the average transmission rate should be straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

A hard coded example using `ifconfig`. For longer term monitoring `vnstat` is more appropriate.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
INTERFACE=wlp2s0
A=($(ifconfig $INTERFACE | grep bytes | sed -e 's/[(|)]//g' -e 's/:/ /g' -e 's/  */ /g'))
sleep 30
B=($(ifconfig $INTERFACE | grep bytes | sed -e 's/[(|)]//g' -e 's/:/ /g' -e 's/  */ /g'))
echo -e ${A[@]}"\n"${B[@]}
AVG=$(expr ${B[2]} - ${A[2]})
AVGKB=$(echo AVG | awk '{ byte =$1 /1024; print byte " KB" }')
#AVGMB==$(echo AVG | awk '{ byte =$1 /1024/1024; print byte " MB" }')
#AVGMB==$(echo AVG | awk '{ byte =$1 /1024/1024/1024/; print byte " GB" }')
echo -e "30 sec average\n"$AVG"\n"$AVGKB
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is the following script, based on `ifconfig` and one my previous answer, [where](https://askubuntu.com/a/963618/566421) are provided more explanations.

- *The script is available as GitHub repository at: https://github.com/pa4080/traffic-get*

**1.** Create executable script file, called `get-traffic`, that is located in `/usr/local/bin` to be accessible as shell command ([more detailed steps](https://askubuntu.com/a/968971/566421)).

**2.** The content of the script `get-traffic` is:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Set the default values or Read the users input
[ -z "${1}" ] && IFACE="eth0"  || IFACE="$1"       # Get the name of the target interface, default: eth0
[ -z "${2}" ] && UNIT="MB"     || UNIT="$2"        # Get the unit (B, KB, MB, GB, Kib, Mib, Gib), default: MB
[ -z "${3}" ] && PERIOD="30"   || PERIOD="$3"      # Get the period of measure in seconds, default: 30
[ -z "${4}" ] && OUTPUT="verb" || OUTPUT="${4,,}"  # Get the type of the output (verbose, all, incoming, outgoing, total) in lower case, default: all
LANG=C # Set envvar $LANG to `C` due to grep, awk, etc.

# Do the conversion
if   [ "$UNIT" == "B"   ]; then UN="1"
elif [ "$UNIT" == "KB"  ]; then UN="1000"
elif [ "$UNIT" == "KiB" ]; then UN="1024"
elif [ "$UNIT" == "MB"  ]; then UN="1000000"
elif [ "$UNIT" == "MiB" ]; then UN="1048576"
elif [ "$UNIT" == "GB"  ]; then UN="1000000000"
elif [ "$UNIT" == "GiB" ]; then UN="1073741824"
else echo "Wrong UNIT."; exit 1; fi

# Whether the $PERIOD is integer
if ! [[ "$PERIOD" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then echo "Enter the PERIOD in seconds"; exit 1; fi

# Get the IP address of the interface
get_ip(){ /sbin/ifconfig "$IFACE" 2>/dev/null | grep -Po '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' | head -1; }

# The main program: If the interface has IP adders it is UP
if [[ "$(get_ip)" =~ ${IPPT} ]]; then
        bRX="$(/sbin/ifconfig "$IFACE" | grep -Po "RX bytes:[0-9]+" | sed 's/RX bytes://')" # Get the incoming traffic into the Beginning of the period
        bTX="$(/sbin/ifconfig "$IFACE" | grep -Po "TX bytes:[0-9]+" | sed 's/TX bytes://')" # Get the outgoing traffic into the Beginning of the period
        bXX=$(( bRX + bTX )) # Calculate the total traffic into the Beginning of the PERIOD

        sleep "$PERIOD" # Sleep for the PERIOD, seconds

        eRX="$(/sbin/ifconfig "$IFACE" | grep -Po "RX bytes:[0-9]+" | sed 's/RX bytes://')" # Get the incoming traffic into the End of the period
        eTX="$(/sbin/ifconfig "$IFACE" | grep -Po "TX bytes:[0-9]+" | sed 's/TX bytes://')" # Get the outgoing traffic into the End of the period
        eXX=$(( eRX + eTX )) # Calculate the total traffic into the End of the PERIOD

        RX=$(awk -v e="${eRX}" -v b="${bRX}" -v un="${UN}" 'BEGIN{ print ( e - b) / un }') # Calculate the amount of the incoming traffic for the PERIOD
        TX=$(awk -v e="${eTX}" -v b="${bTX}" -v un="${UN}" 'BEGIN{ print ( e - b) / un }') # Calculate the amount of the outgoing traffic for the PERIOD
        XX=$(awk -v e="${eXX}" -v b="${bXX}" -v un="${UN}" 'BEGIN{ print ( e - b) / un }') # Calculate the amount of the total traffic for the PERIOD

        # Output
        if   [[ "$OUTPUT" =~ ^verb ]]; then printf 'Interface: %s\nUnit: %s\nPeriod of measure: %s sec.\n\nReceived: %s\nTransmited: %s\nTotal: %s\n' "$IFACE" "$UNIT" "$PERIOD" "$RX" "$TX" "$XX"
        elif [[ "$OUTPUT" =~ ^all  ]]; then printf '%s\n%s\n%s\n' "$RX" "$TX" "$XX"
        elif [[ "$OUTPUT" =~ ^in   ]]; then printf '%s\n' "$RX"
        elif [[ "$OUTPUT" =~ ^out  ]]; then printf '%s\n' "$TX"
        elif [[ "$OUTPUT" =~ ^tot  ]]; then printf '%s\n' "$XX"
        else echo "Wrong OTPUT type."; fi
else
        echo "The INTERFACE \"$IFACE\" is down."
fi
```

- [*Read here about the calculations.*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40787/201297)

**3.** The script call syntax:

```bsh
get-traffic <interface name> <units of measurement> <period of measure> <type of the output>
```

```bsh
get-traffic enp0s25 MiB 30 total
```

**4.** Input parameters:

- `<interface name>` use the command `ifconfig` to get the interface name. Default: `eth0`
- `<units of measurement>` available values: `B`, `KB`, `KiB`, `MB`, `Mib`, `Gb`, `Gib`. Default: `MB`
- `<period of measure>` in seconds. Default: `30`
- `<type of the output>` available values: `verbose`, **`all`**, `incoming`, `outgoing`, `total`.

**5.** Examples of usage:

[image]